# How do connect different http method to same action on routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am begginer for Ruby on Rails.I want to know how to connect different http request (to same url) to same action as follows.

now

```
resources :hoge do
  fuga do
    put :piyo
    patch :piyo
  end
end
```

I want

```
resources :hoge do
  fuga do
    put,patch :piyo
  end
end
```

Ruby enginners love 'DRY' mind so I think  helper method exist like this.If don't exist, I want to know good helper method definition.

I think `concern`in routes.rb isn't I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `match`:

```
match 'piyo', via: [:put, :patch]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the very I want!. Output of `rake routes`  'piyo PUT|PATCH' is also easy to understand.